# Trying to call a constructor from a method java

Tags: java, constructor, class-method

I am trying to call a constructor a return the results in a method

```
//constructor 2
/**
 * @param parker the car that is parked
 * @param parkee the parking meter reading the car
 */
private ParkingTicket( Car parker, ParkingMeter parkee){
    //retrieves the values for license plate, minutes parked, and minutes parked in the class
    this(parker.getLicensePlate(),
        parker.getMinutesParked(),
        parkee.getMinutesPaid()
    );
}
```

This is the method I am trying to return the constructor in.
I want to create a new parking ticket if the minutes parked for exceeds the minutes paid for.

```
//checks if a parking ticket will be issued
public static Integer checkParking(){
    //creates a static method of the minutesPaid non-static method
    //from the ParkingMeter class
    ParkingMeter parkingMeter = new ParkingMeter();
    parkingMeter.getMinutesPaid();

    //creates a static method of the minutesParked non-static method
    //from the Car class
    Car car = new Car();
    car.getMinutesParked();

    if (parkingMeter.getMinutesPaid() > car.getMinutesParked()){
        new ParkingTicket( parker, parkee);}


    else return null;            
}
```

Comment: Note that currently you're *creating* the `ParkingTicket` but not doing anything with it. Did you mean to return something? Perhaps your return type should be `ParkingTicket` rather than `Integer`? Also note that your condition is the wrong way round at the moment. (Compare your description with your code...)

Comment: You need to say more about your problem clearly. Okay? [Edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/33685940/edit) it now.

Comment: This code will not complete . You are not returning anything from the "if" section of the code.
Also please read through : https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/constructors.html

Constructor declarations look like method declarations—except that they use the name of the class and have no return type